# Does Bitcoin Core accepts uncompressed address generation?

Tags: bitcoin-core, public-key, address-generation, command-line-options

So one priv key express uncompressed and compressed pub key.

Does the latest Bitcoin Core client accepts importing it to express uncompressed address? or it automatically express compressed address?

I have not noticed related parameter for compression options in getnewaddress and importprivkey.

Is this because compressed addresses helps reduce transaction size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import an old uncompressed key. It'll work fine.  Getnewaddress always uses scripts with 'compressed' keys now.  BIP-143 (segwit) style inputs also require compression.

The smaller key format results in smaller transactions, and where it's required and not just optional also simpler code.